# Select rows closest to a given value

Tags: python, pandas

```
          A   B       C
0  01:00:00  24  Andrew
1  01:00:00  28     Edd
2  01:00:00  17    Emma
3  01:00:00  10    Fred
4  02:00:00  11  Andrew
5  02:00:00  35     Edd
6  02:00:00  45    Emma
7  02:00:00  14    Fred
```

I want to select one row per each `A` group, with next conditions:

- Select the closest `B` value to 15 (in the case of `01:00:00` closest value to `15` is `17`; in `02:00:00`,  select `14`).

Output should be:

```
          A   B       C
2  01:00:00  17    Emma
7  02:00:00  14    Fred
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need:

```
df = df.loc[df['B'].sub(15).abs().groupby(df['A']).idxmin()]
print (df)
          A   B     C
2  01:00:00  17  Emma
7  02:00:00  14  Fred
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['B'].sub(15).abs())
0     9
1    13
2     2
3     5
4     4
5    20
6    30
7     1
Name: B, dtype: int64

print (df['B'].sub(15).abs().groupby(df['A']).idxmin())
A
01:00:00    2
02:00:00    7
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

**Explanation**:

1. First subtract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) and get absolute values
2. [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `A` and per group get indices of minimal values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html)
3. Select rows by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)